# Why would a future method not show up in debug logs?

Tags: apex, callout, future, asynchronous

What are some possible reasons a future method wouldn't show up in the debug logs?

```
@Future(Callout=true)
global static void myFutureCallout(Id testId){...
```

Comment: kinda hard to say without seeing your code. otherwise, a simple debug log will eventually show up in your logs.

Comment: Future methods should show up in the logs (plural), but would not show up in the log that ran it. In other words, all of the code that ran before calling the future method would be in one log, then the future method itself would be in another.

Comment: @NathanaelSchmolze I am able to see other future method logs so I know it's not the user/log that I am tracking. If it should always show up then I have to assume the future method isn't being called. Am I correct to assume that?

Comment: I believe that you have checked *FutureHandler* log, to track the future method (since, you seem to have tracked other future methods). It is possible that your future method was not called. Were you able to check Setup / Monitoring / Apex Jobs, if they indeed ran?

Comment: @KannanNarayanan thank you for this reminder. I was able to finally get the future method to call and found that it wasn't being called by my user but instead by an automation user the company had created for webservices. I wasn't tracking this "user" so wasn't able to see any of the future logs - just tracked and now it is showing up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Future methods, once called, are only temporary until a database commit occurs. If an operation causes a partial or total rollback, this will include the future method calls, as well as any emails sent, other related DML operations, Schedulable jobs, and so on. As such, there are four ways a future method may not execute.

## Partial DML

Writing code like the following:

```
Database.insert(records, false);
```

Can cause a transaction to be tried up to 3 times. If all of the records fail, or the final version of the transaction didn't call the future method, this would cause the future method to not be called, even if a previous iteration of the transaction fired the future method.

One potential way this could happen is with the use of a poorly written "recursion blocker," which I've warned about in other answers, like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210186/2984).

That code looks like:

```
public class RunOnce {
  static Boolean hasRun = false;
  public static Boolean shouldRun() {
    return hasRun? false: hasRun = true;
  }
}
```

...

```
trigger X on Y (after insert) {
  if(RunOnce.shouldRun()) {
    MyClass.futureMethod();
  }
}
```

If you're using this pattern, make sure you read my other answer to avoid this problem.

## Explicit Rollback

This is pretty straight-forward; if you roll back manually, you'll undo the future method:

```
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
MyClass.futureMethod();
Database.rollback(sp);
```

The future method must survive to the end of the transaction in order to fire.

## Implicit Rollback

If your transaction fails to run to completion, because of governor limits, a failed assertion, or an uncaught exception, you'll lose the future method call as well.

```
// CPU limit example
MyClass.futureMethod();
while(true); // infinite loop
```

---

```
// Assert example
MyClass.futureMethod();
System.assert(false, 'Why it\'s simply impassible! Why, don\'t you mean impossible? No, I do mean impassible. Nothing\'s impossible!');
```

---

```
// Uncaught exception example
@AuraEnabled public static void myMethod() {
  MyClass.futureMethod();
  throw new AuraHandledException('Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die.');
}
```

---

## Daily Governor Limits

There are other unusual edge cases, such as if you reach the 250,000 asynchronous executions per day; waiting a day would help resolve this problem.

---

## Called, But Not Logged

Aside from that, if your debug logs are full, you won't be able to log any future logs until you reduce the total size below 1GB. One easy way to do this is outlined in this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_debug_log_delete.htm&type=5).

> Let me explain... No, there is too much. Let me sum up. --Inigo Montoya

In the Developer Console, use the Query tab to run the following Tooling API query:

```
SELECT Id, StartTime, LogUserId, LogLength, Location FROM ApexLog
```

Select the rows you want to delete, then click the delete button. Repeat until you've cleared up enough space for your new logs.

---

## Wrong Session

In the Debug menu in the Developer Console, there's a "Show My Current Logs Only" option. This might hide logs you'd otherwise see. Try unchecking this.

## Debug Logs Untracked

If you set up a TraceFlag for a user, then only for specific classes, it may be that you're not generating a log, either. This is kind of an edge case, but you can check this out in the Developer Console under Debug > Change Log Levels.

---

If you really, truly can't seem to get this to work, it might be time to contact Technical Support. This answer covers all the expected scenarios that could cause you to "lose" a future method, anything beyond that is likely a bug in the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Also your debug level must be able to catch some thing the future method does. So try to increase the level of the existing ones (eg: from info to fine) or add another category (eg: Database).